# Spacing/Kerning of footnotes before and after punctation

Tags: spacing, footnotes, kerning

I would like to change the space/kerning between footnotes and punctations. Please see my MWE for explanation.

MWE:

```
\documentclass [] {scrbook}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{footnote}{70}
A sentence with a footnote which describes a word\footnote{Description of the word}. The next sentence.

A part sentence with a footnote,\footnote{Description of the part sentence} and the other part of the sentence.

\end{document}
```

In the case of the first sentence I would like to move the dot a bit to the left so it starts where the right border of the serif of the `1` from `71` ends.

In the case of the second sentence I would like to move the footnote `72` a bit more to the left so that the `7` is directly to the right of the comma.

I know the package `fnpct`, but I don't want to switch the position of punctation and footnote, because it would change the meaning of the footnote (like in the first sentence it would refer to the complete sentence instead of only one word).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that `\negthinspace` is what you're looking for.

```
\documentclass [] {scrbook}
\newcommand{\kf}{\negthinspace\relax}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{footnote}{70}

A sentence with a footnote which describes a 
word\footnote{Description of the word}\kf. 
The next sentence.

A part sentence with a footnote,\kf\footnote{Description of the part sentence} 
and the other part of the sentence.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is it be possible to integrate it into the footnote command? Moreover I use biblatex with autocite in footnote style. So it would be nice if the citation footnotes behave the same as normal footnotes.

Comment: @user2653422 You want the negative space in different places and probably sometimes you don't want it, so you have to tell TeX what to do in each case.

Comment: Not exactly. I always want this negative spacing for both footnotes and the footnotes of biblatex. With the manual insertion of `\kf` I see the problem that the command will sometimes be forgotten. But it is correct in the first case `\kf` needs to be before the punction and in the second case after it. So it might be no easy solution doing it in an automatic way, but it would still be a nice feature.

Comment: @egreg: your solution works very well but not with `\footcite`?!

Comment: @LukasCB Sorry, but your question is too abstract. Please, ask a new question with an example of code.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I was wrong, it does work with `footcite`, too.